# How can I setup a way to toggle between highlighting cells that match list A to matching list B?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, format, subset

I have a list of data and I want to be able to toggle between highlighting one subset to highlighting another subset.  Is there a way to toggle between highlighting subset A to highlighting subset B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Data Validation and Conditional Formatting Combination

- Select cell `A2`. Select `Data > Data Validation > Data Validation` and under `Allow:` choose `List` and under `Source:` input `1;2`.
- Select range `C2:H11`. Select `Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule` and select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` and in the text box below add the following formula:

```
=OR(AND($A$2=1,ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,$J$2:$J$6,0))),AND($A$2=2,ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,$K$2:$K$6,0))))
```

and select `OK` and `OK`.

- If you select `1` in cell `A2` the numbers from the `J` column are highlighted, and if you select `2`, the numbers from the `K` column are highlighted.

[image]